# Surface Integral of $\frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $$\vec{v} = \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3},$$ $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$.
>   Evaluate
>
> $$ \iint\limits_S \vec{v} \cdot \vec{n} \, dS$$
>
> with $\vec{n} $ pointing to the exterior of the surface $S$ and $S$
>   being a closed and smooth surface which contais the origin at the
>   interior.
>
> Answer: $ 4 \pi$.
>
> Sugestion: Consider a sphere centered at the origin contained at the
>   interior of $S$.

**My attempt**: For spheres centered at the origin with radius $a > 0$, the surface integral will always be $4 \pi$. Can we bound $S$ between 2 of those spheres and use properties of the integral? I mean,

$$ 4 \pi \leq \iint\limits_S \vec{v} \cdot \vec{n} \, dS \leq 4 \pi?$$

Comment: Why would that inequality follow from bounding $S$ between two spheres? Here's another hint: What is the divergence of $\vec v$?

Comment: I think Giiovanna is trying to consider an *arbitrary* surface by saying that surface is *between* two spheres of different radii.  It's an interesting approach, but I see no way to conclude that such an integral should be bounded in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divergence of $\vec v$ is zero everywhere *except* the origin.

In complex analysis, one would say that the origin is a pole of a meromorphic function, and to find the integral of of the function around a bounding curve, one only needs to know if the pole is inside the region bounded by the curve.

Vector functions that are divergenceless and curlless everywhere except a few isolated points are exactly the 3d analogues of meromorphic functions.  Because the function is divergenceless and curlless everywhere except the single point (the origin), you can use the divergence theorem in the following way:

Let $M$ be a sphere that is wholly contained inside the surface $S$.  Let $T$ be the region between the surfaces $M$ and $S$.  Then the divergence theorem tells us that

$$\int_S \vec v \cdot d\vec S - \int_M \vec v \cdot d\vec S = \int_T \nabla \cdot \vec v \, dV$$

There are a few more details here you should convince yourself of to be sure that this leads to the correct result: for instance, why did I put a minus sign on the integral over the sphere $M$?

But the net result is that, just as in complex analysis, the exact shape of the bounding surface does not matter here, as long as it ultimately bounds the "pole".

Answer (score 2):

I will sketch the argument and let you fill in the details.

First write $\frac{\vec{r}}{ |\vec{r}|^3 }$ as $ \frac{ \hat{r} }{ |\vec{r}|^2 }$. Then,

$$ \int_{S} \vec{v} \cdot d \hat{S} = \int_{S} \frac{ \hat{r} }{ |\vec{r}|^2 } \cdot |\vec{r}|^2 \sin{\theta} d \theta d \phi \hat{r} = 4 \pi   $$

Note: There is a interesting phenomena going on here, for if we calculate the divergence of $\frac{\hat{r}}{|\vec{r}|^2}$ we get 0, but this means (applying the divergence theorem), that the integral above should be 0. What is going on here? To lead you in the right direction, the Dirac delta function, $\delta (\vec{r} )$, fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The statement of the question suggests that the answer is independent of the particular surface, as long as it is closed, smooth, and contains the origin.  Thus, first, we check the statement for a sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin.  The surface area of such a sphere is $4\pi R^2$ and on that surface $\|\vec{v}\| = 1/R^2$.  Thus, the value of the integral for that particular surface is $4\pi R^2 \cdot 1/R^2$.

Now the question is - why should the value be independent of surface?  The answer lies in the fact that the divergence of $\vec{v}$ is zero.